# Repeated measure multilevel regression model

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I have to test for correlation between Thermal inertia (TI) and Depth diameter ratio(d/D), Rim irregularity(RI), Radii variation(RV), mantled rim percentage(MRP). I want to see which variable (RI, RV,d/D, MRP) is affecting the change in thermal inertia values. The thermal inertia values are derived from a scene, the scene itself consists of uncertainty, due to this TI values are dependent upon the error associated with these scenes. Total 19 scenes are present. The number of observations is 130, but each observation was measured twice so the observation becomes 260. TI values are nested within scenes.

Variation in TI values was observed so I have to look for correlation of TI with RI, RV, d/D, MRP, and to test what variable is affecting this variation in TI values.

I have 19 groups, each group consists of craters. For each crater repeated measurements of TI, RI, RV, d/D, and MRP (2 times measurement was taken for each crater) were calculated.

I have to use the “multilevel” and “lmer” functions of R.

How to formulate these in r, if anyone could help me in formulating the tests, it will be of great help to me.

[image: craters nested within groups]

Comment: Please explain the study design and your reseatch questions in more detail, Also, what is RI, RV, d/D and MRP ? Also, please list all the variables in your dataset along with an explanation of what they are

Comment: I hope now my question makes sense, let me know if you need any explanation